# Why is this code printing "123" instead just 3?

Tags: c, printf, curly-braces

I've got some code here:

```c
int n = 0;
for(n = 1;n<4;n++)
printf("%d",n);
return 0;
```

Why does it return '123' instead of just '3'?

I tried to Google for this issue, but I couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: The loop iteration contains one statement (even though not indented). The first loop prints `1`. The second loop prints `2`. The third loop prints `3`. You left no gap in between. BTW it isn't 'returning' what you think. `printf` returns the number of characters output.

Comment: @randanee Why would you expect code which starts at n = 1, and iterates by 1 to n = 4, while printing on each iteration where n < 4, to only print once?

Comment: ... as in `int retval = printf("randanee"); printf("\n%d\n", retval);` which should output your name and `8`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After asking my question, I think I see what you are getting at.

What you have with

```
    int n = 0;
    for(n = 1;n<4;n++)
        printf("%d",n);
    return 0;
```

is functionally the same as

```
    int n = 0;
    for(n = 1;n<4;n++)
    {
        printf("%d",n);
    }
    return 0;
```

Since the for loop expects a statement, either a block of statements enclosed in braces, or a single one terminated with a semicolon as you have in your example. If you wanted it to just print 3 and for whatever reason wanted to use a loop just in increment a number, you would want to provide it with an empty statement as such:

```
    int n = 0;
    for(n = 1;n<3;n++);
    printf("%d",n);
    return 0;
```

or

```
    int n = 0;
    for(n = 1;n<3;n++){}
    printf("%d",n);
    return 0;
```

Both of which will only print 3.

Please note that because the variable `n` gets incremented and then checked, using your original bounds `n < 4`, the loop would end when `n = 4` and thus `4` would be printed. I changed this in my last two examples. Also note the incorrect use of the term return, as some comments pointed out.

Comment: @cocomac I rejected the suggested edit because the indentation was intentional; that code came from inside a main() function and was thus indented as it would be in actual code, which I hoped to express through the indentation. I searched quickly but was unable to immediately find any guidance on if it is standard to indent snippets when outside of their full compliable code, and stylistically, I prefer it this way. If you have any official guidance on that, please link it to me and I will happily make the change if it would be more in compliance with SO guidelines or norms. Thanks!